# Resource recommendations

Tags: book-recommendation

I learned recently of the fact that there were algebraic solutions to the finding the roots not only 2nd degree polynomial but also third and fourth degree (cubic and quartics). I was wondering, thereafter, if there might be anyone here who would be able to point me to a resource. (Preferably a textbook or PDF) wherefrom I might learn these solutions. I would appreciate any advice greatly!

Comment: Quartic: http://www2.trinity.unimelb.edu.au/~rbroekst/MathX/Quartic%20Formula.pdf

Comment: Wikipedia: [cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Algebraic_solution) and [quartic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation).